# Update ProgressBar onTouch and restart it on release (with imageButton)

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am trying to achieve the following design/functionality: I have a circular image that is surrounded by a circular progress bar. I want when the user touches the imageButton the progress bar to start its progress like that:

[image]

The problem is when the user decides to remove their finger from the imagebutton (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) the progress bar does not stop and return to its initial state (0).

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public CircleProgressBar progressBar;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private int totalProgressTime = 100;
Thread t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    progressBar = (CircleProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.custom_progressBar);
    t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int jumpTime = 0;

            while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
                try {
                    sleep(200);
                    jumpTime += 5;
                    final int finalJumpTime = jumpTime;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(finalJumpTime);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(!t.isAlive()){
                    t.start();
                }else {
                    t.stop();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onTouch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                t.interrupt();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Event type: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not fully understanding what you need. Is the progress bar stopping and returning to it's initial state on ACTION_UP the problematic or desired behavior?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have been more clear.It is the desired behaviour. I want when the user do ACTION_UP before the progress bar reaches 100 to reset itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how to use a Thread.  The bottom line is that you shouldn't really be using a Thread like this in Android.  It's almost never advisable to start a thread from an activity (easy mistake if you came from a Java background and are learning Android; I did the same thing).  Also, read the javadoc for [Thread.stop](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop(java.lang.Throwable)).  You should never be calling that method, ever.

What you probably want to do instead is learn how to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to schedule tiny bits of works to run on the main thread at some interval.  Keep scheduling new bits that perform the rendering you want until something sets a flag to tell it not to schedule that bit any more.  You'll solve your problem without using a separate thread at all.

Comment: Thank you very much @Daug Stevenson, I solved my problem using a AsynkTask. Do you think that is a better idea?

Comment: AsyncTask schedules its work on another thread.  I don't think in your case there is any need to use a different thread for any work. The work you're trying to do just needs to be scheduled at an interval on the main thread, and that's what a Handler can do for you.